# CSP with .htaccess to allow iframes from my app

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy, hybrid-mobile-app

I have need to build a component in my mobile app that lists information in an iFrame; the information is hosted my webserver to be served up by PHP scripts.  I am going to be adding certain security/authentication methods to validate the each user is allowed to access the page and if allowed serve the content back to the iFrame in the app.

Is there any CSP method that I could use to help further lock down the page so it can't be access or referenced in iFrames from elsewhere?

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.myDomain.com com.myApp.*"`

Where `com.myApp` is my app name that could be used directly in the CSP or with an `X-Requested-With` header.  I know `X-Requested-With` is not secure but it def could be one more mechanism to cut down on unauthorized traffic?

If so, how would I write the CSP policy to do one...or both?

Comment: An `X-Requested-With` header has little to do with CSP. You can check for whether that is set some other way, if you like.

Comment: Well, thats why I am asking.  Trying to find a way to allow frame-ancestors for my app only - or looking for a way to lock down http requests coming from my app.

Comment: Not sure what "ancestor" you would have here, if your app is not running this in a context where a host name would be in use in the first place, then you can't limit it based on that via CSP.